# How to convert xml file to jmx file in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Please refer the XML data below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="File Upload &amp; Download scenario" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676249/jmeter-file-upload-and-file-download-scenario</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="testURL" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">testURL</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">www.datafilehost.com</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="testFile" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">testFile</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">upload.txt</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="scriptPath" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">scriptPath</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </Arguments>
      <hashTree/>
      <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${testURL}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">Java</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">4</stringProp>
      </ConfigTestElement>
      <hashTree/>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1429126843000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1429126843000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="get-upload-page" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <XPathExtractor guiclass="XPathExtractorGui" testclass="XPathExtractor" testname="XPath Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.default">NOT_FOUND</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.refname">MAX_FILE_SIZE</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.xpathQuery">//input[@name=&quot;MAX_FILE_SIZE&quot;]/@value</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.validate">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.tolerant">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.namespace">false</boolProp>
          </XPathExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="UPLOAD-FILE" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">MAX_FILE_SIZE</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/upload.php</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">true</boolProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
            <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
              <elementProp name="${scriptPath}${testFile}" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
                <stringProp name="File.path">${scriptPath}${testFile}</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.paramname">upfile</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.mimetype">text/plain</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="-1758146177">Your file has been successfully uploaded!</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">2</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <XPathExtractor guiclass="XPathExtractorGui" testclass="XPathExtractor" testname="XPath Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.default">NOT_FOUND</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.refname">accessURL</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.xpathQuery">//input[@name=&apos;download&apos;]/@value</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.validate">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.tolerant">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.namespace">false</boolProp>
          </XPathExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">downloadID</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">${testURL}/d/(.*)</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NOT_FOUND</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Sample.scope">variable</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Scope.variable">accessURL</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="get-download-page" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">${accessURL}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="-2066876936">Invalid file ID.</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">6</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <XPathExtractor guiclass="XPathExtractorGui" testclass="XPathExtractor" testname="XPath Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.default">NOT_FOUND</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.refname">downloadURL</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="XPathExtractor.xpathQuery">//a[*[@alt=&apos;Download&apos;]]/@href</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.validate">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.tolerant">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="XPathExtractor.namespace">false</boolProp>
          </XPathExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="DOWNLOAD-FILE" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">${downloadURL}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="49586">200</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">8</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="-2066876936">Invalid file ID.</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_data</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">6</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResultSaver guiclass="ResultSaverGui" testclass="ResultSaver" testname="Save Responses to a file" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="FileSaver.filename">downloaded_${downloadID}_</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="FileSaver.errorsonly">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="FileSaver.skipautonumber">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="FileSaver.skipsuffix">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="FileSaver.successonly">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="FileSaver.variablename">downloadedFile</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="FileSaver.addTimstamp">true</boolProp>
          </ResultSaver>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="false">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="false">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="SummaryReport" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Summary Report" enabled="false">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.jmx` files **are** `.xml` files so you don't have to do any conversion, just save the above file as `.jmx` and open it using JMeter GUI. You should see something like:

[image]

Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article to learn more about how to properly simulate file upload and download events using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener.

Comment: TQ so much for ur guidance its helpful alot@Dmitri T